# Функция вычисления факториала

Tags: математика, ruby, факториал

Столкнулся с непонятной проблемой при попытке реализации простой задачи. Нужно вычислить факториал числа, передаваемого параметром командной строки.

```
def fact n
 f = 1
 for i in 2..n
   f *= i
 end
 f
end
puts fact(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

Вывод программы при любых значениях передаваемого аргумента равен 1.

При замене

```
puts fact(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

на

```
a = gets.chop!.to_i
puts fact(a)
```

все работает. Как я понимаю моя ошибка в неправильной передаче аргумента, но как правильно его передать я не знаю.

Comment: @hopkins, а как вы передаете аргумент?, у меня все нормально работает ![](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1WC7cTW6Y6hY0XfNiN1KTFoV48oZFZ.png)  ![](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1l6HXomQBCb6CH5fIYs2qt24pMKFGH.png)

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, просто захожу через терминал в папку с программой и пишу

    ruby fact.rb 0
    1
    ruby fact.rb 4
    1
    ruby fact.rb 15
    1

при любом аргументе он мне выдает единицу.

Comment: проверил у себя - код работает нормально (факториал вычисляется). Попробуйте в начало функции добавить вывод аргумента, что бы видеть, что именно попало в функцию. Подозреваю, что там 0. В этом случае нужно будет придумать, как передать число, что бы оно не было числом одновременно (но пара идей у меня есть).


А какая у Вас ОС или Вы с под веба запускаете (к примеру, ideone.com)?

Comment: В таком случае выделяйте проблему из общей программы.

Если ошибка в передаче аргумента, то посмотрите, что вообще передается в программу и протестируйте вывод аргументов, без запихиваний в функцию факториала.

        puts ARGV.size

        ARGV.each do |a|
          puts "Argument: #{a}"
        end

И запускайте:

> ruby test_argv.rb 1 10 20
> ruby test_argv.rb --test=10 arg a
> ruby test_argv.rb r b -w 12

Comment: @KoVadim, я пробовал и на Windows 7 и на Windows 8. Пробовать на unix системах займет слишком много времени, так как она нигде у меня не установлена.

Сделал как вы сказали:

    def fact n
    puts n
     f = 1
     for i in 2..n
       f *= i
     end
     f
    end
    puts fact(ARGV[0].to_i)

Вывод программы получился следующий:

    fact.rb 2
    0
    1

То есть в функцию передается уже 0. Может это какая-то особенность передачи аргументов в Windows? Хотя в C++ все нормально передается.

Comment: значит, в аргумент попадает то, что не может конвертироваться в число. Распечатайте входные аргументы и посморите, что там, как предложил @Alex Krass

Comment: Сократил всю программу до:

    puts ARGV[0] * 2

и получаю следующую ошибку:

    undefined method '*' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

получается, что аргументом передается ничего

Comment: давайте улучшим. передайте не один аргумент, а штук пять.

    fact.rb 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо большое! Преобразуйте комментарий в ответ пожалуйста, я отмечу, что вопрос решен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот ответ на Ваш вопрос - SO. Да, может такое быть, что нет параметров, это винда:) Но это лечится. Там в первом ответе все описано.

Answer (score 3):

```
def fact(n)
  if n == 0
    1
  else
    n * fact(n-1)
  end
end

puts fact(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

Comment: @Vetal4eg, и этот вариант я тоже пробовал. Тот же результат. В самом алгоритме вычисления факториала ошибки нет. Ошибка кроется в передаче аргумента.
Если ARGV[0].to_i я заменю на число, к примеру 3. То программа исправно выдает правильный результат.